# IServiceProvider is disposed in singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In ASP.NET core I have a singleton service, which is using a scoped service, that itself needs to instantiate new services itself.

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddSingleton<MySingleton>();
      services.AddScoped<MyScoped>();
   }
}

public class MySingleton
{
   private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
   public MySingleton(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
   {
      _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
   }

   public async Task Foo()
   {
      AsyncServiceScope serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
      await serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyScoped>().Bar();
      await serviceScope.DisposeAsync();
   }
}

public class MyScoped
{
   private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
   public MyScoped(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
   {
      _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
   }

   public async Task Bar()
   {
      AsyncServiceScope serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
      SomeType s = await (SomeType)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceScope .ServiceProvider, someType);
      s.DoSomething();
      await serviceScope.DisposeAsync();
   }   
}
```

After some time, I receive an error when `await serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyScoped>().Bar();` is called:

> You can not access an already disposed object. IServiceProvider!.

Why do I receive this error and what is the best way to get arrount it?
I already tested with injecting `IServiceProvider`, `IServiceProviderFactory` and `IServiceScopeFactory`.

In my understanding the `IServiceScopeFactory` should prevent accessing an already disposed ServiceProvider.

Comment: I'd consider flipping your logic around. If `MySingleton` has a scoped dependency, then (logically) it too is effectively scoped. Because at least one of its dependencies is scoped. You could flip this by extracting the genuinely singleton part of `MySingleton` into another dependency - I'll try demonstrating in an answer shortly.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue by copy/pasting the code in an empty console application, but wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I also noticed the code you posted doesn't compile, making me believe that this is not the actual code that exhibits the problem. Try to construct a Minimal, Reproducible Example out of this code, i.e. a the minimal amount of code that demonstrates the issue, and is a fully working application that can be copy/pasted and ran by any experienced developer who might try helping you.

Comment: From the code you now posted, however, I see no reason why this could could fail. `IServiceScopeFactory` is a singleton, thread-safe dependency and both scopes and singleton classes should be able to use it. Your demonstrates scenario should work. So I expect there's something going on that you are not showing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your example, to check I've understood.

Let's assume you want to use a Singleton because (say) there's a large amount of data that's initialised once. And then the rest of the logic needs to be Scoped.

So you create a Singleton which tries to take a Scoped dependency:

```cs
public interface IBarScoped
{
    void Bar();
}

public interface IFooSingleton
{
    void Foo();
}
```

```cs
public class FooSingleton : IFooSingleton
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _singletonHugeAmountOfData;
    private readonly IBarScoped _scoped;

    public FooSingleton(IBarScoped scoped)
    {
        // 1. Great, we can set up our singleton data.
        _singletonHugeAmountOfData = CreateLotsOfData();

        // 2. But... This doesn't work.
        // When the Scoped dependency changes, how will your DI re-generate your singleton?
        // Answer is: it can't.
    }
}
```

This doesn't make sense. You're asking that your Singleton gets re-constructed every time the Scoped dependency changes? Everything Scoped gets disposed once that execution finishes.

But you don't want the whole thing to be Scoped, because of your large Dictionary initialisation.

So instead: flip your thinking so that your Singleton becomes *mostly* Scoped, for anything that depends on other Scoped dependencies. Then extract the *genuinely* standalone part into a different Singleton, which *doesn't* depend on anything Scoped.

`Foo` is no longer a Singleton. It's now Scoped. Everything works.

```cs
public interface IBarScoped
{
    void Bar();
}

public interface IFooScoped
{
    void Foo();
}

public interface IDataSingleton
{
    IDictionary<string, string> SingletonHugeData();
}
```

```cs
public class FooScoped : IFooScoped
{
    private readonly IDataSingleton _singletonData;
    private readonly IBarScoped _scoped;

    public FooScoped(IDataSingleton singletonData, IBarScoped scoped)
    {
        // 1. Great, we can set up our singleton data.
        _singletonData = singletonData;

        // 2. And also, Foo can now be declared as scoped,
        // which means we can take an IBarScoped dep as well.
        _scoped = scoped;
    }
}
```